# Main not waiting for threads even after using Thread.join() in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, java-threads

join() is supposed to make main function wait until all the threads complete execution, but main is printing `completed` before `Thread-1` and `Thread-2` completes execution.
I am unable to find error in the code. where's the mistake?

```
class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;

    ThreadDemo(String name) {
        threadName = name;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " exiting.");
    }
    public void start() {
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread (this, threadName);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
public class Problem2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadDemo T1 = new ThreadDemo("Thread-1");
        ThreadDemo T2 = new ThreadDemo("Thread-2");
        T1.start();
        T2.start();
        try {
            T1.join();
            T2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!");
        }
        System.out.println("completed");
    }
}
```

Output

```
completed
Thread Thread-2 exiting.
Thread Thread-1 exiting.
```

Comment: Aside from what was already mentioned by JB Niezt, don't extend Thread. More info: [“implements Runnable” vs “extends Thread” in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/541487). Also what is the point of `private Thread t;` if your class already `extends Thread`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're joining on the ThreadDemo instances. But you're not running these instances as threads. Your overridden `start` method creates and starts another Thread.

Your code is extremely convoluted. You use both inheritance and delegation, and you override methods and break their contract: start() is supposed to start `this` as a thread, not create and start another thread.

Here's what it should look like:

```
class ThreadDemo implements Runnable {
    private String threadName;

    ThreadDemo(String name) {
        this.threadName = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " exiting.");
    }

}
public class Problem2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadDemo runnable1 = new ThreadDemo("Thread-1");
        ThreadDemo runnable2 = new ThreadDemo("Thread-2");

        Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable2);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!");
        }
        System.out.println("completed");
    }
}
```